Issue deleting input tags Vue 3/ shadcn
I am trying to delete some input tags using the shadcn element <TagsInputItemDelete/>  in a form
It works fine for values that are strings, but I am having issues when the values are objects.
I have these definitions where skills works when clicking the “x” to remove the input tag and selectedCompetencies does not.
const selectedCompetencies = ref<{ id: string; label: string }[]>(
 props.initialValues.competencies || []
);


const skills = ref<string[]>(props.initialValues.skills || []);

When you click the “x” on the input tag, the tag doesn’t get removed/deleted if the value is an object. My guess is that it might be comparing the entire object ({id, label}) to decide what to remove.
Here is the part of the from where tags are added and removed from the form:

       <FormField v-slot="{ componentField }" name="competencies">
           <FormItem class="mt-2">
             <FormLabel>
               Competencies
             </FormLabel>
             <TagsInput
               v-bind="componentField"
               class="px-0 gap-0"
               :model-value="selectedCompetencies"
               @click="handleClick"
             >
               <div class="flex gap-2 flex-wrap items-center px-3">
                 <TagsInputItem
                   v-for="item in selectedCompetencies"
                   :key="item.id"
                   :value="item.label"
                 >
                   <TagsInputItemText />
                  <TagsInputItemDelete/>
                 </TagsInputItem>
               </div>


               <ComboboxRoot
                 v-model="selectedCompetencies"
                 v-model:open="open"
                 v-model:searchTerm="searchTerm"
                 class="w-full"
               >
                 <ComboboxAnchor as-child>
                   <ComboboxInput
                     placeholder="Please select competencies from the dropdown"
                     as-child
                   >
                     <TagsInputInput
                       class="w-full px-3"
                       :class="selectedCompetencies.length > 0 ? 'mt-2' : ''"
                       @keydown.enter.prevent
                    />
                   </ComboboxInput>
                 </ComboboxAnchor>


                 <ComboboxPortal>
                   <CommandList
                     position="popper"
                     style="z-index: 100"
                     class="w-[--radix-popper-anchor-width] rounded-md mt-2 border bg-popover text-popover-foreground shadow-md outline-none data-[state=open]:animate-in data-[state=closed]:animate-out data-[state=closed]:fade-out-0 data-[state=open]:fade-in-0 data-[state=closed]:zoom-out-95 data-[state=open]:zoom-in-95 data-[side=bottom]:slide-in-from-top-2 data-[side=left]:slide-in-from-right-2 data-[side=right]:slide-in-from-left-2 data-[side=top]:slide-in-from-bottom-2"
                     @click="handleClick"


                   >
                     <CommandEmpty />
                     <CommandGroup>
                       <CommandItem
                         v-for="comp in filteredCompetencies"
                         :key="comp.id"
                         :value="comp.label"
                         @select.prevent="
                           (ev) => {
                             if (typeof ev.detail.value === 'string') {
                               searchTerm = '';
                               selectedCompetencies.push(comp);
                             }
                             if (filteredCompetencies?.length === 0) {
                               open = false;
                             }
                           }
                         "
                       >
                         {{ comp.label }}
                       </CommandItem>
                     </CommandGroup>
                   </CommandList>
                 </ComboboxPortal>
               </ComboboxRoot>
             </TagsInput>
           </FormItem>
         </FormField>

If I need to, I can update the logic to explicitly handle the removal of the input tags based on the id by modifying the deletion event to find the competency by its id and then remove it from selectedCompetencies. Something like this:
<TagsInputItem
  v-for="item in selectedCompetencies"
  :key="item.id"
  :value="item.label"
>
  <TagsInputItemText />
  <TagsInputItemDelete @click="removeCompetency(item.id)" />
</TagsInputItem>

and adding
const removeCompetency = (id: string) => {
  selectedCompetencies.value = selectedCompetencies.value.filter(item => item.id !== id);
};

However, I don’t understand why using the backspace/delete key on the keyboard seems to remove the tags with objects without any problem from both selectedCompetencies and the form. If add removeCompetency, I think I will also need to update the form to to set form.values.competencies = selectedCompetencies.value; as the form doesn’t seem to get updated automatically and the removed competencies still seem to send even though selectedCompetencies seems to get updated. Meanwhile, using the <TagsInputItemDelete/> as is without using a custom event listener seems to automatically update the form data as well, so I would prefer to use it as is if possible.
TL;DR
1.Why is there a difference in behavior between the delete/backspace keyboard button vs the <TagsInputItemDelete/>?
2.I would prefer to use the default behavior of <TagsInputItemDelete/> if possible as it seems to automatically update the form data. Does it seem possible to get it to work leaving <TagsInputItemDelete/> as it is or does it seem like I would need to create a new method to handle removing the competencies? (If so, please explain why).
Thanks!
